# Sort array elements alphabetically after sorting numerically

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

Suppose I have an array:

```
arr = ["Tom, 2, 6","Bill, 3, 8","Lisa, 4, 7","Charles, 2, 8"]
```

I know I can use `arr.split(',',2).pop();`, for example, to extract the 2nd elements in each string and a custom compare function to sort them. However, how might I sort alphabetically after having sorted numerically?

In this case, for example, the strings with Tom and Charles in them, both have a 2 following the first comma. Sorting numerically would place Tom ahead of Charles, but, I would like them to appear in alphabetical order as well. So how might I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a custom callback function in `sort()`

```js
var arr = ["Tom, 2, 6", "Bill, 3, 8", "Lisa, 4, 7", "Charles, 2, 8"];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  a = a.split(',').map(o => o.trim());     //Split a and trim
  b = b.split(',').map(o => o.trim());     //Split b and trim

  if (a[1] !== b[1]) return a[1] - b[1];   //Check if the second value is not the same, if not the same sort using the second value
  return a[0].localeCompare(b[0]);         //Since second value is the same, use the first value to sort
})

console.log(arr);
```

---

Using the last name (2nd word) to match

```js
var arr = ["Tom Peters, 2, 6", "Bill Burgess, 2, 8", "Lisa Cooper, 4, 7", "Charles White, 2, 8"];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  a = a.split(',').map(o => o.trim()); //Split a and trim
  b = b.split(',').map(o => o.trim()); //Split b and trim

  if (a[1] !== b[1]) return a[1] - b[1]; //Check if the second value is not the same, if not the same sort using the second value
  return a[0].split(' ')[1].localeCompare(b[0].split(' ')[1]); //Since second value is the same, use the first value to sort
})

console.log(arr);
```

Doc: [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Works great! I probably should have said so in my question, but the names in my array include last names. I tried using `return (a[0].split(" ",2).pop()).localeCompare(b[0].split(" ",2).pop());` to sort by last name, but it had the same effect as your answer. Any suggestions?

Comment: @codeEnthusiast Can you give an example of the array with lastname? So sort it by lastname?

Comment: `var arr = ["Tom Peters, 2, 6", "Bill Burgess, 3, 8", "Lisa Cooper, 4, 7", "Charles White, 2, 8"]` - the desired result after sorting by the second element numbers is for Tom Peters to be ahead of Charles White, by virtue of last name.

Comment: @codeEnthusiast Are we assuming the `second` word is the last name. Right? User might have a name "John Paul Peters". Or just use the`last` word?

Comment: Yes. The second word is assumed to be the last name.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try sort after?

```
arr.sort();
```